# Implementing a Multiple (Checkbox) Select + "Other" widget in Django

Tags: python, django, forms, validation, modelform

I need to populate a CharField with the result of a set of checkboxes plus an "other" [please specify] option (the value would be 'option-a,other' for the form state below). The form can basically look like:

```
[x] option a
[ ] option b
[x] other

If you selected "other", please specify. [__________]
```

I've managed to get most of the way there by Implementing a subclass of MultipleChoiceField:

```
class CommaStringMultipleChoiceField(MultipleChoiceField):
    def to_python(self, value):
        return [val.rstrip().lstrip() for val in value.split(',')]

    def clean(self, value):
        return ",".join([val.rstrip().lstrip() for val in value])
```

In my form class, I assign that field to my form field:

```
TYPE_CHOICES = [
    (u'option-a',u"Option A"),
    (u'option-b',u"Option B"),
    (u'other', u"Other"),
]

type = CommaStringMultipleChoiceField(
    choices=TYPE_CHOICES,
    widget=CheckboxSelectMultiple
)
```

This renders the form properly, and my custom clean() method is called, but when I save the form I get a validation error:

```
Value u'education,other' is not a valid choice.
```

I've played with adding a custom validator, but that hasn't made any difference so far. What am  missing?

Comment: There is an article that might help you fixing something similar. The main change to that article is to subclass another widget. [The article.](http://garmoncheg.blogspot.com/2014/05/implementing-multiple-radio-select.html)

Answer (score 1):

As the error only occurs once you save a model instance out of the form, check if the “Value u'education,other' is not a valid choice” error is coming from *model* validation instead of *form* validation. That can happen if you also have a `choices` set on the model field when you really want to store a free-form string there.

Answer (score 0):

You will probably need to override the Validate method on your class. In the code at https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/forms/fields.py#L682 you'll see where it is raising the error message.

Comment: I did override validate() and valid_value(): https://gist.github.com/3327b22ecdc0f8abca8f but I'm still getting validation errors. Is there a way to shortcut any other validation?

Comment: Digging through the code. The error message you are getting doesn't come up in the code phrased that way. Is another class catching it somehow? You might want to catch Validation errors and dump a traceback so you can see exactly where it's coming from.